# How to get the value of SharedPrefences before the Widget build() , i.e before the UI is built.?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Initially when The Screen loads it Show an error

```
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.

'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':

Failed assertion: line 269 pos 10: 'data != null't
```

Later after a few seconds, the value gets Stored into the _emailSF variable.

This is the instance of the Stateful widget class HomeScreen , 
The main requirement of this quest is to get the value of a field of a SharedPreferences before the UI build has happened.

getValuesSF is the async function which initialises the value for the variable _emailSF;

```
class DrawerWidget extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final String title;

  String _emailSF;

  DrawerWidget({this.title});

  @override
  void initState() {
    print("*****TAG:HomeScreen*****: initState");
    super.initState();
    getValuesSF();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("*****TAG:HomeScreen*****: $_emailSF");
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.blue),
        title: Text(
          "Flutter For Beginners",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        // Add a ListView to the drawer. This ensures the user can scroll
        // through the options in the drawer if there isn't enough vertical
        // space to fit everything.

        child: ListView(
          // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.

          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[
            AppDrawer().createHeader(_emailSF),
            AppDrawer().createDrawerItem(icon: Icons.home, text: 'Home'),
            ExpansionTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.mobile_screen_share),
              title: Text(
                "Examples",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
              ),
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 70),
                    title: Text(
                      "Stack",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/stack');
                    }),
                ListTile(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 70),
                    title: Text(
                      "Scoped Model",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/counter');
                    }),
                ListTile(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 70),
                    title: Text(
                      "Http Request",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/fetch');
                    }),
                ListTile(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 70),
                    title: Text(
                      "StatefullWidget",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/StateFullWidget');
                    })
              ],
            ),
            AppDrawer().createDrawerItem(
                icon: Icons.open_with,
                text: 'Product',
                onTap: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/product')),
            Divider(),
            AppDrawer().createDrawerItem(
                icon: Icons.mobile_screen_share,
                text: 'Logout',
                onTap: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/product')),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[Center(child: Text("Home Screen"))],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  getValuesSF() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    // Return String
    setState(() => this._emailSF = prefs.getString('email'));

    print(
        "*****TAG:LoginScreen*****:------getValuesSF() Email-------${prefs.getString('email')}");
    //Return double
  }
}
```

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59028883/what-is-the-correct-way-to-get-the-value-which-has-been-stored-using-sharedprefe/59029055#59029055

Comment: @RavinderKumar this solution is not that clear . Please elaborate the answer with more code , As i'm a beginner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to prevent build however you can choose to display the header only after the _emailSF is loaded from shared preferences as below.

```
class DrawerWidget extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final String title;

  String _emailSF;

  DrawerWidget({this.title});

  @override
  void initState() {
    print("*****TAG:HomeScreen*****: initState");
    super.initState();
    getValuesSF();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("*****TAG:HomeScreen*****: $_emailSF");
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.blue),
        title: Text(
          "Flutter For Beginners",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        // Add a ListView to the drawer. This ensures the user can scroll
        // through the options in the drawer if there isn't enough vertical
        // space to fit everything.

        child: ListView(
          // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.

          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[
            if(_emailSF != null)
            AppDrawer().createHeader(_emailSF),
            AppDrawer().createDrawerItem(icon: Icons.home, text: 'Home'),
            ExpansionTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.mobile_screen_share),
              title: Text(
                "Examples",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
              ),
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 70),
                    title: Text(
                      "Stack",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/stack');
                    }),
                ListTile(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 70),
                    title: Text(
                      "Scoped Model",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/counter');
                    }),
                ListTile(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 70),
                    title: Text(
                      "Http Request",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/fetch');
                    }),
                ListTile(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 70),
                    title: Text(
                      "StatefullWidget",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/StateFullWidget');
                    })
              ],
            ),
            AppDrawer().createDrawerItem(
                icon: Icons.open_with,
                text: 'Product',
                onTap: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/product')),
            Divider(),
            AppDrawer().createDrawerItem(
                icon: Icons.mobile_screen_share,
                text: 'Logout',
                onTap: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/product')),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[Center(child: Text("Home Screen"))],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  getValuesSF() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    // Return String
    setState(() => this._emailSF = prefs.getString('email'));

    print(
        "*****TAG:LoginScreen*****:------getValuesSF() Email-------${prefs.getString('email')}");
    //Return double
  }
}
```

**What's changed?**
instead of `AppDrawer().createHeader(_emailSF)`, use `if(_emailSF != null) AppDrawer().createHeader(_emailSF),`